# How do I know what does EF translate Linq queries into?

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, translation

On many sites/blogs I noticed that people, who want to explain linq mechanism, write Linq Queries and provide SQL translation for that. How can I get the translation for my own queries?
I'm working with EF .Net 4.0 in VS2010. Is there a place (property or even some third-party tool) where I can see what they're being translated into?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you should look at [EFProf](http://efprof.com/). Yes it's a commercial tool, but man is it awesome. (There are free ways to do it too, such as SQL Profiler)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you, it works perfectly and I'm satisfied with 30-days trial :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest method is to use SQL Profiler.  I have found this a real god-send when it comes to debugging.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for but I have only Express edition of MSSQL, so I would have to play with some more-advanced edition installer's scripts to get the profiler, so I just pass now as I'm in hurry.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [ObjectQuery.ToTraceString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx) method:

```
var query = ...
string sql = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString();
```

However, some shortcomings of this approach is that it will only show queries, not updates/inserts/deletes. Also, it won't reveal the parameters used.

If you need as much detail as possible from the query then use the SQL Server Profiler as [Neil suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8563422/59111).

Julie Lerman has a good article with different options on MSDN: [Profiling Database Activity in the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx). She mentions:

- [ObjectQuery.ToTraceString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx) method
- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate's IntelliTrace
- [EFTracingProvider](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers)

Comment: Yeah, it's really limited and does not allow to translate a lot of queries that I would like to, thanks however :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), you can query your entity model and view the generated SQL.